# PL/SQL select returns more than one line

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm embarrassed to admit this is a totally noob question - but I take shelter in the fact that I come from a T-SQL world and this is a totally new territory for me

This is a simple table I have with 4 records only

**ContractorID        ProjectID        Cost**

```
 1              100        1000
 2              100        800
 3              200        1005
 4              300        2000
```

This is my PL SQL function which should take a contractor and a project id and return number of hours ( 10 in this case )

```
create or replace FUNCTION GetCost(contractor_ID IN NUMBER, 
                                          project_ID in  NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    ContractorCost  NUMBER;    

BEGIN
    Select Cost INTO  ContractorCost
    from Contractor_Project_Table
    where ContractorID= contractor_ID and ProjectID =project_ID ;
    return ContractorCost;
END;
```

But then using

```
select GetCost(1,100) from Contractor_Project_Table;
```

This returns same row 4 times

```
1000
1000
1000
1000
```

What is wrong here? WHy is this returning 4 rows instead of 1

Thank you for

Comment: `getCost()` is called once **for each row** in `Contractor_Project_Table` so you get as many rows as are present in that table. Why don't you just use a regular join - that will be much more efficient than using that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have 4 rows in Contractor_Project_Table table. Use this query to get one record.

```
select GetCost(1,100) from dual;
```

Comment: thanks...this worked.... though this concept of  having to put dual in it sounded a bit meh....  but well, oracle is the way it is .

Answer (score 3):

As @a_horse_with_no_name points out, the problem is that `Contractor_Project_Table` has (presumably) 4 rows so any `SELECT` against `Contractor_Project_Table` with no `WHERE` clause will always return 4 rows.  Your function is getting called 4 times, one for each row in the table.

If you want to call the function with a single set of parameters and return a single row of data, you probably want to select from the `dual` table

```
SELECT GetCost( 1, 100 )
  FROM dual
```